# Use CDI alternative with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cdi

I'm searching a way to change the CDI Alternatives at deployment time. We use jenkins to build our application. Is there a means to handle this in Jenkins.
The perfect thing would be a field where i can select the alternative before the build. I don't know jenkins very well. So maybe you can help me in my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be to use [CDI events lifecycle](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#_container_lifecycle_events) like "AfterBeanDiscovery" and veto the alternative that we don't want to be used. But beans.xml solution must be used first if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since alternatives are activated via `beans.xml`, its not possible to do it at deployment time.  Apache DeltaSpike provides a solution that would allow you to configure at deployment time - https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/spi.html#GlobalAlternative